# "Command 'import' not found, but can be installed with" in MiniConda

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda, miniconda

I'm trying to run python scripts in Miniconda/Anaconda on WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I've created an environment with Python 3.7.10 and I got an error message when I try to import packages every time. The message is:

```
Command 'import' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install imagemagick-6.q16                  # version 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2, or
sudo apt install imagemagick-6.q16hdri              # version 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2
sudo apt install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat  # version 1.4+really1.3.35-1
```

If I'm correct, the `import` command should be included in Python, and graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat package is a set of applications to manipulate image files so I think installing these imagemagick packages won't provide help.

I also tried to use #!/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/venv/bin/python, but it doesn't work.

All I had done after installing Ubuntu and Anaconda/Miniconda include:

```
conda create -n venv python=3.7.10 numpy
conda activate venv
import numpy
```

Otherwise, in the venv environment, both of `which python` and `python --version` work, but the environment can't find `import` command. I'm confused that it can find python and its path, but it can't find the `import` command which is belonged to Python.

But, if I only input `python`, it works. <strike>However, in this situation, I may not find and import packages that are already installed in the environment (in another environment that contains other packages I want to use).</strike>

```
which python
/home/chihhao/miniconda3/envs/venv/bin/python

python --version
Python 3.7.10
```

Could anyone provide some help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should go through a python tutorial. You can start with https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html.

You want to run `import` in a python shell or a python script. Right now, you are running it in a bash terminal, and bash doesn't know what `import` means.

```sh
user@foo:~$ conda activate venv
user@foo:~$ python
Python 3.8.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Oct  7 2020, 19:08:05) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

If you have a python script with the name `script.py` and the contents

```py
import numpy
```

you can run it with `python script.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem is solved now. I did try to use `Python` before I post the question. At that time I don't know why, but I can't import a package I thought I already installed in the environment. But I can't replicate the situation again.

Comment: That can happen if you have multiple python installations or multiple conda environments. Each one can have different packages.